PySide2 pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget() multiline live update charts x axis problem
'I have modified the PySide2  mouse hover chart code to multiline live update. I Consider that lines and x-axis ticks will pass by from right to left, according to the timer data update. Still, when I run the code, line data are added from the right side of the chart as it has to be but the left side stays on zero point, therefore due to appending more and more data to the chart, it finally overloaded and stacked. I can't find an error in the code, please help with that
import math
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui

class HoverableCurveItem(pg.PlotCurveItem):
    sigCurveHovered = QtCore.Signal(object, object)
    sigCurveNotHovered = QtCore.Signal(object, object)

    def __init__(self, hoverable=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HoverableCurveItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.hoverable = hoverable
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def hoverEvent(self, ev):
        if self.hoverable:
            if self.mouseShape().contains(ev.pos()):`your text`
                self.sigCurveHovered.emit(self, ev)
            else:
                self.sigCurveNotHovered.emit(self, ev)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(\*args, \*\*kwargs)

        self.view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
    
        self.x = list(range(10))  # 100 time points
        self.y = [[0] * 10] * 5
    
        self.colors = ['#ED4BFF','#FF46B2','#FF3C4F','#FF9041','#FFAB4B']    
   
        print(len(self.colors))
        # create plot
        self.plot = self.view.addPlot()
    
        ###========= TIMER  ==================================
    
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(500)
        self.z = 0
    
    def update(self):
    
        self.z += 0.1
        sensors = []
        data = []
        self.x = self.x[1:]  # Remove the first x element.
        self.x.append(self.x[-1] + 1)  # Add a new value 1 higher than the last.
        for i in range(5):
            sensors.append((math.sin((i + self.z) / 8) + 1) * 3)
            sensors[i] = round(sensors[i], 2)
            self.y[i] = self.y[i][1:]  # Remove the first
            self.y[i].append(sensors[i])  # Add a new value.
    
            data.append(dict({
                'x': self.x,
                'y': self.y[i],
                'pen': pg.mkPen(self.colors[i], width=1),
                'name': i
            }))
    
        # Use a data array to run the loop
        for curveData in data:
            plotitem = HoverableCurveItem(**curveData)
            plotitem.sigCurveHovered.connect(self.handleHovered)
            plotitem.sigCurveNotHovered.connect(self.handleNotHovered)
            self.plot.addItem(plotitem)
    
    
    def handleHovered(self, curve: HoverableCurveItem):
        print(curve.name())
    
        curve.setPen(pg.mkPen(self.colors[curve.name()], width=5))
    
    def handleNotHovered(self, curve: HoverableCurveItem):
        curve.setPen(pg.mkPen(self.colors[curve.name()], width=1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(1400, 450)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

